# how to set time out function in ajax success call?

Tags: jquery, ajax

**how to set the set timeout function in below my code(#chat_log) every three seconds it will be refresh without page reload or refresh**

**form**

```
<div class="messages msg_sent">
    <?php $timestamp1 = strtotime($row->msg_sent_time); ?>
    <?php $mesgtimming = date(' D-h:i A', $timestamp1); ?>
    <p>
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-placement="right" title="<?php echo $mesgtimming; ?>"><?php echo $row->message; ?> </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

**script**

```
  success: function (data)
    {

    $('#chat_log').append('<div class="row msg_container base_receive"><div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12"><div class="messages msg_receive"><p><a>' + message + '</a></p></div></div></div>');

    $('#messagee').val('');
},
```

Comment: Please show all relevant code and what you have tried

Comment: Question is unclear to me. Do you want to run the ajax call every 3 seconds ? If you want to do something periodically you would use **setInterval** - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: i want to run every 3 seconds    $('#chat_log').append('<div class="row msg_container base_receive"><div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12"><div class="messages msg_receive"><p><a>' + message + '</a></p></div></div></div>'); @codtex

Comment: I don't see where `message` variable is coming from. Do you expect it to come from the result of your Ajax call? It probably is updated at some point but from where? You can call this code once `message` is updated